# How we can preview list of documents in ngx-doc-viewer?

Tags: angular, ngx-doc-viewer

I am using an angular package, I am having an array of documents which includes images and pdf documents. The demo and documentation of the package are showing one file in the viewer, however, my requirement is to display an array of documents in the viewer. suggestions and alternatives are welcome.

link of the package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching about the issue, I found that this is impossible to achieve in the local environment because google viewer needs an online link to the file to preview, so it is not supporting local files to display.

Comment: I was struggling and as soon as pointed to AWS S3 URL it is working now. Thank U